# Module variable scoping in Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: evaluation, scoping, asynchronous-processing

I ran across a scoping puzzle while experimenting with [ScheduledTasks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateScheduledTask.html?q=CreateScheduledTask&lang=en), and I'd be grateful for an explanation from the sages here.  I found a workaround by intuitive horse sense, but was unable to explain to myself adequately what was wrong with my original attempt.

First, a straightforward, tail-recursive, synchronous [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html?q=Module&lang=en)

```
Module[{state = 0, doNextIteration},
 doNextIteration = Function[
   state = state + 1;
   If[state < 4,
    (Print[state]; doNextIteration[])]];
 doNextIteration[]]
(* 1 2 3 *)
```

Next, my first attempt to do the same with asynchronous tasks, which I need to tail-chain as one-shot ScheduledTasks.  If [CreateScheduledTask](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateScheduledTask.html?q=CreateScheduledTask&lang=en) has a second `List` argument, then it creates a one-shot task delayed by the time in seconds in the list, just what I need for my bigger application.  In this simplified sample, the ScheduledTask tail-chains a new one-shot ScheduledTask by a tail-recursive call -- just like the successful synchronous code -- once every tenth of a second until the condition on `state` produces False (ignore cleanup of the task objects for simplicity, here).

```
Module[{state = 0, runNextTask},
 runNextTask = Function[
   StartScheduledTask@
    CreateScheduledTask[
     state = state + 1;
     If[state < 4,
      (Print[state]; runNextTask[])],
     {0.10}]];
 runNextTask[]]
```

OK, the problem is this only Prints once, not the desired three times.  I had a **sickening hunch** that the problem has something to do with `runNextTask` being local to the `Module` and somehow not being able to refer to itself recursively -- even though there is only one `Module` -- in the bizzaro-land of asynchrony, so I "fixed" the code as follows:

```
Module[{state = 0, runNextTask = Unique[]},
 runNextTask[] :=
  If[state < 3,
   StartScheduledTask@
    CreateScheduledTask[
     Module[{},
      state = state + 1;
      Print[state];
      runNextTask[]],
     {0.10}]];
 runNextTask[]]
```

I made `runNextTask` refer to a [Unique](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unique.html?q=Unique&lang=en) global symbol, and made my function into a rewrite rule attached to `runNextTask[]`.  This works great, but I don't understand well why it does.  I hate being as dumb as a horse, even if I can jump the fences.

Clues, advice, explanations: all appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You hit a rather subtle behavior, related to the garbage-collection and the `Temporary` attribute, and the semantics of `Module` regarding returning expressions. The thing is, to achieve your goal, you need the `Module`-generated variable (function)'s definition(s) to be exported outside `Module` (to be persistent). But, since you return not the symbol itself, but its r.h.s. (which is a chunk of code with delayed evaluation, either `Function` or `ScheduledTaskObject` in this case), the definitions of `runNextTask` are destroyed because it has a `Temporary` attribute, *despite the fact* that code containing this variable has been exported outside `Module`.

To illustrate my point, here are two work-arounds which both will lead to your desired effect:

1. Instead of assigning `runNextTask` to `Unique[]`, insert a line `ClearAll[runNextTask]` right after the `Module` declarations. This will remove the `Temporary` attribute and the definition of `runNextTask` will persist.
2. Wrap your final call in `Hold` (so, return `Hold[runNextTask[]]`), and then use `ReleaseHold` outside `Module`.

This is your code for this option:

```
res = 
 Module[{state = 0, runNextTask},
   runNextTask[] :=
     StartScheduledTask@
       CreateScheduledTask[
         state = state + 1;
         If[state < 4,
           (Print[state]; runNextTask[])
         ],
         {0.10}];
   Hold@runNextTask[]]

ReleaseHold[res]
```

In this case, the definition also persists.

Note that this problem is not seen in examples where all evaluation happens at the time when `Module` is left: the following code will execute promptly

```
Module[{f, n = 0},
  f[] := (n++; If[n < 10, Print["*"]; f[]]);
  f[]]
```

even though all definitions for `f` are destroyed at the end - because the execution here is immediate (the same evaluation process, so that `f` still has all definitions during this evaluation), while delayed and asynchronous code induces a separate evauation process.

Comment: Thanks for this clue! I have a follow-on that seems to be related coming in a new question.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Glad I could help. I actually did not previously encounter this exact behavior, so I learned something too. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: good explanation, thanks for that. I just wanted to mention that, if the function is just called for the side effect like here, one could just do this to make the definition persist: `Module[{state = 0, runNextTask}, 
 runNextTask = 
  Function[StartScheduledTask@CreateScheduledTask[state = state + 1;
     If[state < 4, (Print[state]; runNextTask[])], {0.10}]];
 runNextTask[];
 Hold@runNextTask]`

Comment: @Albert Indeed, a good option! I did not think about it, thanks.

Comment: Well, actually shortly after my comment I decided that I would actually recommend to rather use `Unique` than `Module` to create the symbol: Not only because no additional "tricks" are needed to make things work. It also seems easier to guess what the code actually is supposed to do for a reader. As far as I can see the OP is using the version I'd recommend anyway...