# Difficulty catching thrown errors in asynchronous tasks

Tags: evaluation, scoping, asynchronous-processing

In [this Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/module-variable-scoping-in-scheduled-tasks), Leonid explained that module variables can get garbage collected from a chain of asynchronous tasks unless their `Temporary` attribute is cleared either by calling `ClearAll` on them or by Holding them.  This works for preserving a variable that refers to the function that creates asynchronous task.  The next step is to create a variable that Catches a value Thrown inside an asynchronous task, but the same technique does not seem to work, as I illustrate below.

First, a synchronous version that works as I need. This has an internal synchronous task wrapped in a `Catch.`  By default, the `Catch` returns a symbolic value that is `Unique`; that is the default, "OK" case.  Internally to the `Catch`, the task bumps a state variable, checks that the state value is ok, prints it if so, throws it if not, and schedules the next iteration of the task up to a maximum state value.  "Ok" in this contrived example means that state's value is less than 2; in a real application, it would be based on some unpredictable outcome, hence the whole reason for `Catch`.  The following code implements the scheme above and works fine, printing `1` and then `ERROR`:

```
Module[{
  state = 0,
  runNextTask,
  catchResult,
  defaultCatchResult = Unique[]},
 runNextTask = Function[
   catchResult = Catch[
     If[state < 4,
       state = state + 1;
       If[state < 2, Print[state], Throw[state]];
       runNextTask[],
      {0.10}];
     defaultCatchResult];
   If[catchResult =!= defaultCatchResult, Print["ERROR"]]];
 runNextTask[]]
```

Now, I want to do the same asynchronously, attempting the following code, wherein the only differences to the synchronous versions are marked with comments:

```
Module[{
  state = 0,
  runNextTask,
  catchResult,
  defaultCatchResult = Unique[]},
 (* the following device removes the "Temporary" 
 attributes from "runNextTask" and "catchResult." *)
 ClearAll[runNextTask, catchResult];
 runNextTask = Function[
   catchResult = Catch[
     If[state < 4,
      (* the following invocation techniques make the
      body here asynchronous. *)
      StartScheduledTask@
       CreateScheduledTask[
         state = state + 1;
         If[state < 2, Print[state], Throw[state]];
         runNextTask[],
        (* This is the amount of time with which to
        separate asynchronous invocations. *)
        {0.10}]];
     defaultCatchResult];
   If[catchResult =!= defaultCatchResult, Print["ERROR"]]];
 runNextTask[]]
```

The problem, now, is that the Thrown value is not caught, as revealed in the message box:

```
1
Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[2] returned to top level.
```

This isn't the end of the world, since at least the repeating chain of asynchronous tasks is interrupted and I can wrap the entire thing in another catch and make it behave well inside other code.  But it's another case where I am uncomfortable proceeding when I don't understand what's going on.  I expected one result and got another!

I will be grateful for advice, suggestions, solutions!

I'll be grateful for any advice, clues, solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why this does not work

The problem here seems to be that `Catch` can only catch exceptions thrown by some code down the *same* evaluation stack, corresponding to the same evaluation process. However, the asynchronous mechanism you use (based on `CreateScheduledTask` etc) induced a *different* evaluation at a specified time, with *another* evaluation stack, and at a later time. So, at any given iteration, your `Catch` is watching for the stack number `n`, while your exception, if thrown, will be in a stack number `n+1` - in other words, your `Catch` is always one evaluation too early.

In order to catch your exceptions, you'd have to place `Catch` inside `CreateScheduledTask` (so that it watches the correct evaluation stack), which would largely destroy the purpose. Therefore, I'd suggest to communicate the state and status of your system (error or not) via flags, which are set inside your code in `CreateScheduledTask`, and checked in your function, rather than using exceptions. You can, of course, still use exceptions to short-circuit the failure inside the code in `CreateScheduledTask`, but not as a communication mechanism between that code and the function which creates it (but see also below).

#### Time travel and lazy evaluation, or how to make it work

However, using exceptions in the fashion you want is *not impossible*, thanks to the lazy evaluation, available in Mathematica. If you insist on minimal modification for your code, then here is how: make your function `runNextTask` accept some arbitrary code as a parameter, and hold it, evaluating only inside body. Then:

```
Module[{state = 0, runNextTask, catchResult,
    defaultCatchResult =  Unique[]},
    (*the following device removes the "Temporary" 
      attributes from "runNextTask" and "catchResult."*)
    ClearAll[runNextTask, catchResult];
    SetAttributes[runNextTask, HoldAll];
    runNextTask =
     Function[
        code,
        catchResult =
          Catch[
             code;
             If[state < 4,
              (*the following invocation techniques make 
                the body here asynchronous.*)
                 StartScheduledTask@
                   CreateScheduledTask[
                     state = state + 1;
                     runNextTask[If[state < 2, Print[state], Throw[state]]],
                     (*This is the amount of time with which to separate 
                      asynchronous invocations.*)
                     {0.10}
                   ]
             ]; (* If *)
             defaultCatchResult
          ]; (* Catch *)
          If[catchResult =!= defaultCatchResult, Print["ERROR"]],
          HoldAll
     ]; (* Function *)
     runNextTask[Null]]
```

Note that the function is now `HoldAll`, as well as the `runNextTask` (the latter isn't really necessary though). By using this construct, I basically pass the code from the "future" to the "past" (from the stack-matching perspective. Of course, it is really the other way around), making it evaluate in a different evaluation stack, now the same as that where `Catch` is - and now it works.

Comment: Thank you once again Leonid!

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I just added a solution which you may find satisfactory - just have a look.

Comment: Here is a gist of an implementation of "GenerateWithTime" from the Reactive Framework that uses todays answers :)  Having a look at your solution right now.  https://gist.github.com/2279799

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Very interesting! Thanks for sharing! I am off for today, but I will surely have a close look at it tomorrow. I am very interested in this kind of things, and don't have much experience with them yet.

Comment: Leonid: two huge lessons is your new solution: the lazy technique AND the fact that `Function` has a third parameter (apparently undocumented!).  Wow!  Big thanks again.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin It (`HoldAll` and other attributes for `Function`) actually is documented, but indeed rather scarcely. Also, in place of a `Function`, you can use a pattern-defined symbol. All that matters is the lazy evaluation. `Function` is just one way to achieve it. And I just noticed that because of lazy evaluation plus code-as-data, we may exchange chunks of unevaluated code between different evaluation stacks, which was the key for matching the stacks here.

Comment: here is a gist with a COMMENTED version of generateWithTime plus a Unit Test https://gist.github.com/2296390

Comment: another gist where generateWithTime is restartable and interleavable https://gist.github.com/2302901

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Reb, thanks a lot. I am temporarily tied up, but as soon as I get time on my hands, I will pay a real close attention to all this. I think this is a really important direction which has been largely ignored in the Mathematica context so far.