# ScheduledTask with scoped variables. Working with timed evaluation

Tags: front-end, evaluation, date-and-time, kernel

I guess I have to try harder and focus more but timed evaluation always frustrates me.

I will show the issue on simple example of delayed trigger.

```
 ClearAll@time; time = 0;
 CreateScheduledTask[time++;, {1, 5}]
 StartScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[];

 DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@time, 
                If[time === 5, RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]; Print["end"]]]
```

> ```
> 1... 2... 3... 4... 5 "end" (*so it works OK*)
> ```

---

In general one may want to scope such procedure:

```
DynamicModule[{x},
ClearAll@x;

Column[{Button["start", x = 0;
                         RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
                         StartScheduledTask@CreateScheduledTask[x++;, {1, 5}]],
         DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@x, If[x === 5, Print@1]]   
          }] ]
```

> output before clicking:
>
> ```
> FE`x$$number (*as expected*)
> ```
>
> output after clicking:
>
> ```
> 0 (*and it does not change*)
> ```

We can see that the only procedure that was enabled was `x = 0;`.

I was suspecting problems because `ScheduledTasks` are not related to `FrontEnd` while `DynamicModule` is.

What is interesting is that changing `DynamicModule` to `Module` fixes the problem.

**The question are:**

- What am I missing in case of `DynamicModule`? I've seen [Module variable scoping in ScheduledTasks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3807/5478) but I couldn't use it for my purpose. (*I've added `ClearAll` but it does not seem to make any difference.
- Schould I use `Module` even if this is only a minimal example of the code that will be implemented in larger cdf? Moreover, [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz) reminded couple of times ([e.g. here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ)) that such constructs are incorrect.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom :) any thoughts?

Comment: unfortunately I don't know much about any of this :(

Comment: My guess is that the update mechanism of `Dynamic` does not generally know about things changed via the scheduled task mechanism, particularly when you localize using `DynamicModule`, which means that the localized variable is owned by the FrontEnd. One way that works is to use something like `Dynamic[x, UpdateInterval -> 1]` instead of just `Dynamic[x]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated**

This happens because your `DynamicModule` returns a dynamic object of which `x` is passed on to the front-end before the scheduled task starts, so the front-end-`x` cannot be modified anymore by any process (more details at the end).

The problem can be further simplified. This works:

```
RemoveScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[];
DynamicModule[{x = 0}, RunScheduledTask[x++, {1, 5}]; Print@Dynamic@x;];
```

but this does not (at least not how one would expect):

```
RemoveScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[];
DynamicModule[{x = 0}, RunScheduledTask[x++, {1, 5}]; Dynamic@x]
```

Examining the second one:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
d = DynamicModule[{x = 0}, Print[HoldForm@x -> x]; 
RunScheduledTask[x++, {1, 5}]; Dynamic[HoldForm@x -> x]]
```

> ```
>  x$1725 -> 0  (* the real name of x inside DynamicModule & the sched.task *)
>
>  FE`x$$18 -> 0 (* the displayed x as returned from DynamicModule *)
> ```

Clearly, the returned `x` has nothing to do with the `x` used in the scheduled task.

As OP realized, `Module` works where `DynamicModule` does not. The same analysis as above:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
d = Module[{x = 0}, Print[HoldForm@x -> x]; 
RunScheduledTask[x++, {1, 5}]; Dynamic[HoldForm@x -> x]]
```

> ```
> x$1740 -> 0  (* the real name of x inside DynamicModule & the sched.task *)
>
> x$1740 -> 0  (* the displayed dynamic value of x as returned from DynamicModule *)
> ```

The two variables are not decoupled, so the scheduled task will modify the same variable that is displayed. The problem here is that the variable that is actually displayed and modified dynamically (`x$1740`) are not owned by the front-end, though it should be according to John Fultz's explanation. **See below for a better solution.**

### Better understanding evaluation sequence

As Leonid has pointed it out, the **returned dynamic** value of a `DynamicModule` is owned by the frontend:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Print@Dynamic@x; Dynamic@x]
```

> ```
> x$4513     (* printed *)
>
> FE`x$$88   (* returned *)
> ```

One can change the first one from the outside as `x$4513 = 99`, but not the second one, so scheduled tasks failed.

Digging deeper, I managed to get to the depths of the problem. The main reason why the returned `x` does not update is because when the return value of the `DynamicModule` is returned and displayed on screen, it is passed on to the front end **without evaluation**, and gets renamed from `x$4513` to `x$$88`. Only after it is displayed will the front end look after how to update `x`, however, the internal scheduled task has already been called before returning `Dynamic[x]` from the `DynamicModule`, and it still refers to `x$4513`, so the two references to `x` gets decoupled and will never be linked anymore.

According to this hypothesis, delaying the scheduled task AFTER the returned value is displayed should work. The correct method for this is to use `Initialization`, that is [evaluated right after](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153/89) the returned value of a `DynamicModule` is displayed:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
d = DynamicModule[{x = 0},
  Print["In DM: ", HoldForm@x -> x];
  Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}],
  Initialization :> (Print["initialized"]; 
    RunScheduledTask[x++; Print["In ST: ", HoldForm@x -> x], {.5, 3}];)
  ]
```

When evaluated, one can see that the two `Print` statements refer to different variables:

> ```
> In ST: FE`x$$11->1
>
> In DM: x$1729->0
> ```

meaning that the scheduled task (`ST` printing) now correctly uses the front-end variable instead of the kernel variable (`DM` printing)! For the whole thing to work, one needs an extra `TrackedSymbols :> {x}` in `Dynamic`, or something similar, to tell the front-end what variable/trigger should be checked. Any of the followings should work:

```
Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
Dynamic@{x}
Dynamic[x, UpdateInterval -> .1]
```

but not this:

```
Dynamic@x
```

Comment: Short answer: use `Module` instead of `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @Kuba Does the edit provide a better understanding of the case? I still don't know exactly why the `Module`-based version is to be avoided, but I fully trust the words of John Fultz. Would be nice if he could throw in some extra information...

Comment: I like the update :) great you've managed to figure it out.  There are always problems with timed procedures/precedence/or evaluation order (at least to me) but this is important part of GUI creation and such problems should already have been discussed in *possible issues* sections. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kuba, fine by me :)

Comment: The solution is to put SchTasks in `Initialization` while relevant variables should be displayed in body via `Dynamic`. Ok. but what if `x` is not meant to be displayed, it is only an iterator or whatever. So it's not going to be displayed, the issue appears again. I can unscope `x` you can say, since it's not for displaying it should not be in `DynModVar`. Ok, but I can't put it in `Module` as the whole body is wrapped in `Dynamic[Refresh[..,None]]` so it will be against "do not put `Module` vars to `Dynamic` internal to that.

Comment: At the end the only solution I can use is to unscope it so `x` is a `Global` variable. It works but this construction is ugly, ugly but forced by MMA design. Or have I missed something? If someting is not clear, feel free to ask :)

Comment: @Kuba So what's wrong with this code? `Module[{x}, Button["start", x = 0; RunScheduledTask[x++; If[x === 3, Print@1], {1, 5}]]]` It scopes `x` and executes button code & sch.task correctly.

Comment: It is what I had to do in this StarWars topic. Variables `op and `h` are `Global` to make it work. I find it ugly.

Comment: In this example there is no `Dynamics` or `DynamicModules`. `If there is only `Module` it is ok. But I'm talkingin context of CDF creation, like http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47273/5478

Comment: @Kuba If I put `h` and `op` in the first argument of the `DynamicModule` the crawl still works nicely at my end.

Comment: Too bad I'm not at home, I can't test it but I remember that it was not so ok for me. I will try this ater and will post you my observations. So, thank you for your time now. I will try to make a MWE later :)

Comment: @Kuba If you find out what the discrepancy is (it still looks ok to me), ping me, I still check SE regularly.

Comment: p.s. Don't you think that the first statement in details section *`DM` first gives unique names to local variables in `expr`, just like `Module`, then evaluates the resulting expression, and then returns a version of this wrapped in `DM`.* is just not true, or at least requires additional info about this first scoping being kernel scoping?

Comment: @Kuba I think that this statement is perfectly true. The variable x$1729 you see above is indeed a localized kernel variable, It is printed by the kernel during the kernel evaluation of the DM-command, before the result was wrapped in another DM and sent to the frontend for constructing the output.

Comment: @FredSimons Maybe the wording is too radical. But what I think is that documentation at least creates missleading view on DM behaviour. AdvDynFunc tutorial says DM variables are owned by FE. Details sections says scoping is done at the beginning. So I see no reason to expect that DM scopes in two different ways. Topics like this are only confirmation - noone expects that, unless has faced it. :/

Comment: @Kuba  The first statement in details section says _DM first gives unique names to local variables in expr, just like Module, then evaluates the resulting expression, and then returns a version of this wrapped in DM._ That means, I think, that the kernel evaluation of a DM results in a DM kernel expression. That resulting DM expression, which you can inspect with InputForm or FullForm, is sent to the frontend for displaying and it is the frontend that localizes the variables in the displayed DynamicBox.

Comment: @FredSimons I don't arguee if it's formally correct or not. My point is that *double* localization by DM is at least not  obvious...

Comment: @IstvánZachar. With much interest I studied your solution, and I agree with some, but not all of your remarks and observations. If after such a long time you are still interested, I just posted another solution, in which I refer to yours.

Comment: @FredSimons and Istvan, [those comments are quite on topic.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13658/enabled-option-for-slider-in-manipulate-not-updating-dynamically#comment42796_13658)

Answer (score 2):

The following is a slightly simplified version of your DynamicModule:

```
DynamicModule[{x},
 Column[{Button["start", x = 0; RunScheduledTask[x++;, {1, 5}]],
 Row[{Dynamic[HoldForm[x]], " = ", Dynamic[x]}]}]
]
```

When you evaluate this for the first time, underneath the button you see the output

```
(* FE`x$$82 = FE`x$$82 *)
```

(very likely with a different DynamicModule number.) Here FE``x\$\$82 is a kernel variable that is created by the frontend to be able to call the kernel with respect to the frontend variable \$CellContext`x$$, that we see when we inspect the cell expression of the displayed DynamicModule.

When we press the button, the output changes to

```
(* FE`x$$882 = 0 *)
```

and nothing indicates that the scheduled tasks were executed. But they are executed! We can ask for the value of the kernel variable:

```
FE`x$$82
(* 5 *)
```

Hence we only have to force the updating. That can be done by including TrackedSymbols:

```
DynamicModule[{x},
  Column[{Button["start",x=0; RunScheduledTask[x++;,{1,5}]],
  Row[{Dynamic[HoldForm[x]]," = ", Dynamic[x, TrackedSymbols:>{x}]}]}]
]
```

Now it works.

A short remark on Istvan Zachar's solution. I think that his explanation is not quite correct. The kernel evaluation of a DynamicModule expression gives another DynamicModule kernel expression and that last one is displayed by the frontend. It can easily be found by converting the displayed DynamicModule (which belongs completely to the frontend) to InputForm. In the adapted example of Kuba it is (I left out the Button options):

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0}, 
  Column[{Button[start, x = 0; RunScheduledTask[x++; , {1, 5}],
  Row[{Dynamic[HoldForm[x]], " = ", Dynamic[x]}]},
   ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}], 
  DynamicModuleValues :> {}
]
```

The variable in the scheduled task is the local variable of the DynamicModule! There is no reason for using the Initialization option for entering the scheduled task. The crucial point is that the updating in Dynamic does not work, whether we implement the scheduled task in the Initialization option or not. Therefore, also in Istvan's solution the option TrackedSymbols in Dynamic is required.