# Creating a warning before executing a function if not cancelled?

Tags: dynamic, dialog-window, scheduling

How could I create a warning dialog that executes a function if not cancelled after a delay ? Also I would like the time remaining before execution to be displayed and the dialog to be non blocking.

Comment: Here's something very similar: [**78017**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78017/5478). P.s. keep in mind that using DM variables in ScheduledTasks may be tricky unless you are paying attention: [**38291**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38291/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SetAttributes[countdownConfirm, HoldRest]

countdownConfirm[msg_, body_] :=
  CreateDialog[
    Column[{
      Row[{msg, " ", 
       Dynamic[If[# > 0, #, DialogReturn[body]; #] & @ 
        Ceiling @ Clock[{5, 0}, 5, 1]]}],
      CancelButton[]
    }]
  ]
```

Test:

```
countdownConfirm["A print will happen in", Print@"A print happened indeed!"]
```

Comment: Nice, and simpler than me. You get the accept.

Comment: I don't think you need to use Setting.

Comment: @faysou Thank you, and I'm glad I could help.  You're right regarding `Setting`; I don't know why I put that in, other than personal confusion.  I also added `DialogReturn[body]; #` because I just noticed a momentary "shudder" in the dialog window before it closes, and this seems to fix it.

Comment: Clock is an interesting function as it manages to update in Dynamic without an explicit symbol to track. There must be a code rewrite behind the scene.

Comment: @faysou I've never thought about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using the function below we can do:

```
ExecuteIfNotCanceled["A print will happen in",Print@"A print happened indeed!"&]
```

This function is interesting as it uses many different aspects of Mathematica.

```
ExecuteIfNotCanceled[message_,function_,delay:_Integer:5]:=
    DynamicModule[{n=delay,decrementTask,closeScheduledTask,dialog,tasks},

        tasks = {decrementTask,closeScheduledTask};

        decrementTask=CreateScheduledTask[n--];         

        closeScheduledTask=
            CreateScheduledTask[
                NotebookClose@dialog;
                RemoveScheduledTask /@ tasks;
                function[];
                ,
                {delay}
            ];

        StartScheduledTask /@ tasks;

        dialog=
            CreateDialog[
                Column[
                    {
                        Dynamic[message~~" in "~~ToString@n~~" seconds.",TrackedSymbols:>{n}]
                        ,
                        CancelButton@DialogReturn[RemoveScheduledTask /@ tasks]
                    }
                    , 
                    Alignment -> Right
                ]
                ,
                Modal->False
            ];
    ];
```