# How to dynamically select a country on a map using the cursor

Tags: dynamic, curated-data, geography

Let's say I have a map of Europe with a locator in manipulate

```
Manipulate[ GeoGraphics["Europe", GeoBackground -> "CountryBorders"], {{p, {150, 150}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Currently I can use the locator to navigate aimlessly around the map. My goal would be to select the country the mouse clicks on, where I am able to process which country has be selected and it is highlighted. It is unnecessary to have a locator, it was the only method I know.

I am aware this is an extensive question and am happy for any advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an approach using [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html), together with [`EventHandler`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) wrappers around the individual `Polygon` directives. It also incorporates a lot of front-end trickery to get a user control that runs entirely in the front-end (avoiding front-end ↔ kernel communication improves the performance significantly, especially for cases like this where a many complex graphics primitives are used)

```
CountrySelector[c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 iCountrySelector[#, c, opts] &
CountrySelector[Dynamic@var_, c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 iCountrySelector[Dynamic@var, c, opts]
iCountrySelector[Dynamic@var_, c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {
    control = Panel@Row@{
      "Loading country selector...",
      ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"]
     }
   },
  Dynamic@control,
  Initialization :> SessionSubmit[
    control = DynamicModule[
      {active, countries = c},
      GeoGraphics[
       {
        MapIndexed[
         EventHandler[
           Style[
            Annotation[Polygon@#, ""],
            TagBoxOptions -> {
              BaseStyle -> FEPrivate`Which[
                FEPrivate`SameQ[active, #2[[1]]],
                {Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@{Thick, Red}},
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue@"MouseOver",
                EdgeForm@Lighter@Red,
                True,
                {}
                ]
              }
            ],
           {
            "MouseClicked" :> (FEPrivate`Set[active, #2[[1]]]; var = #)
            }
           ] &,
         countries
         ]
        },
       opts,
       GeoBackground -> "CountryBorders",
       ImageSize -> Medium
       ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

The control is written to support use as a custom control type for [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html):

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@country,
 {{country, None}, CountrySelector@EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]}
 ]
```

[image]

Standalone use would look like this:

```
CountrySelector[Dynamic@country, EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]}]
```

You can also pass in options to be added to the `GeoGraphics` command, e.g. if you want to change the size or the `GeoBackground`.

Some notes on the implementation:

- The helper function `iCountrySelector` is needed to ensure that `Manipulate` sees a `Function` expression, otherwise it will not use the custom control type.
- Since we need `GeoGraphics` to "see" the `Polygon[...]` directives, we cannot wrap them in `Dynamic` (also, this wouldn't be good for performance). Instead, we have to find a way to apply the styling as an option. The best I could come up with is `TagBoxOptions->{BaseStyle->…}` together with an `Annotation` wrapper (which produces the `TagBox`). One could also use `PolygonBoxOptions` to style the `Polygon` directives directly, but apparently, `FilledCurve` is used for some countries (which would require us to set `FilledCurveBoxOptions` as well).
- The state of the control (i.e. which country is selected) is stored in a `DynamicModule` variable (called `active`
  in the code above)
- We use a separate `active` variable for the control itself. This ensures that the front-end does everything on its own without calling the kernel. (When using a single variable, I think the problem is that the front-end sees the variable used in a complicated `Dynamic` expression, which causes it to do everything over the kernel)
- `` FEPrivate`Set `` is used to set the variable via the front-end, eliminating the need for kernel-communication.
- `` FEPrivate`Which `` and `` FEPrivate`SameQ `` are needed in order to ensure that the style computation can be done by the front-end. (the functions are "documented" [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html#1106674090))
- We use the country index instead of the entity itself for `active`, since the front-end needs to call the kernel otherwise as far as I can tell.
- Since the setup time can be quite long (especially if the country data needs to be downloaded first, the `Manipulate` is prone to timing out, returning `$Aborted`. To fix this, we display a placeholder control, and use [`SessionSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SessionSubmit.html) to complete the control construction asynchronously. We use [`Initialization`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) to ensure that the control is actually updated once it is finished, as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38297/36508).

Comment: This looks good, unfortunately when I run it in version 12.0 the output is Aborted. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Hm... It looks like the initial setup time is too long for `Manipulate`, causing it to time out and return `$Aborted` - I have updated the answer with a workaround (note that the first time it might take quite a while, until everything has been downloaded)

Comment: Wonderful, it works now, thank you. One final question, I am aware this wasn't in the question, but what is the simplest way to CloudDeploy this? As it has been crashing in the ways I tried.

Comment: @TimB unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to adapt the code as it is written now, and I'm not accustomed enough with the cloud stuff to be able to come up with a performant solution. I would therefore suggest you to create a separate question for that