# Cloud Deploy dynamic country selection from a map

Tags: curated-data, geography, cloud-deploy

This is a follow-up question based on the answer I got from Lukas Lang. The original question is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210552/how-to-dynamically-select-a-country-on-a-map-using-the-cursor/210554?noredirect=1#comment539768_210554). How can I alter the code to deploy it on the cloud? Or in case this method is only for desktop: how can I replicate this idea for cloud deploy?

```
CountrySelector[c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 iCountrySelector[#, c, opts] &
CountrySelector[Dynamic@var_, c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 iCountrySelector[Dynamic@var, c, opts]
iCountrySelector[Dynamic@var_, c_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {
    control = Panel@Row@{
      "Loading country selector...",
      ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"]
     }
   },
  Dynamic@control,
  Initialization :> SessionSubmit[
    control = DynamicModule[
      {active, countries = c},
      GeoGraphics[
       {
        MapIndexed[
         EventHandler[
           Style[
            Annotation[Polygon@#, ""],
            TagBoxOptions -> {
              BaseStyle -> FEPrivate`Which[
                FEPrivate`SameQ[active, #2[[1]]],
                {Lighter@Red, EdgeForm@{Thick, Red}},
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue@"MouseOver",
                EdgeForm@Lighter@Red,
                True,
                {}
                ]
              }
            ],
           {
            "MouseClicked" :> (FEPrivate`Set[active, #2[[1]]]; var = #)
            }
           ] &,
         countries
         ]
        },
       opts,
       GeoBackground -> "CountryBorders",
       ImageSize -> Medium
       ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@country,
 {{country, None}, CountrySelector@EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]}
 ]
```

I am looking for any advice or just a point in the right direction.

Comment: I would start with a step by step check, first of all, does this return a list for you: `EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]`? Moreover, I am afraid that ``FEPrivate` `` functionality is not supported in the cloud so you need to use `BasetStyle -> Dynamic @ Which[....` instead. There's no 100% guarantee it will work so at the end you may need to have `Dynamic` wrapped around everything.

Comment: Yes, EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"] does return a list for me. The piece of code functions nicely in Mathematica, however, as you mention there are functionalities that don't work in the cloud. Sure, I'll try that out.